# Segue to a Table View Controller based on what was clicked on in a different Table View Controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, segue

I have a table view controller that is filled with data that is being pulled from a JSON file. This table view controller segues to another table view controller that is pulling from the same JSON file. I want the information that loads into the second view controller to change based on what table cell was clicked on in the first table view controller.

For example: If my first table view controller listed states (Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, etc) and Alabama was clicked on, it would return a list of cities in Alabama. However, if Alaska is clicked on, then the second table view controller would show cities that are in Alaska instead.

I am not exactly sure how to even begin here but here is my code first table view controller didSelectRowAtIndexPath function:
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var industry: Industry!

```
    if inSearch{
        industry = filteredSearch[indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        industry = industryOfMifi[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier("IndustryPush", sender: industry)
}
```

And here is the code that is loading the appropriate information in the second table view controller:

```
  func parseJSON(){
    do{
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/580d0ccce4b0bcac9f837fbe")!)

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

            let industry = anItem["mediaIndustry"] as! String
            if industry == "Interactive Media" {
                let mifiIndustry = anItem["name"] as! String
                print(mifiIndustry)
                let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int
                let newIndustry = Name(mifiName: mifiIndustry, mifiId: mifiId)
                industryOfMifi.append(newIndustry)
            }
            else if industry == "Newspaper" {
                let mifiIndustry = anItem["name"] as! String
                print(mifiIndustry)
                let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int
                let newIndustry = Name(mifiName: mifiIndustry, mifiId: mifiId)
                industryOfMifi.append(newIndustry)
            }
            else if industry == "Radio" {
                let mifiIndustry = anItem["name"] as! String
                print(mifiIndustry)
                let mifiId = anItem["employeeId"] as! Int
                let newIndustry = Name(mifiName: mifiIndustry, mifiId: mifiId)
                industryOfMifi.append(newIndustry)
            }

        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to tell what's going on here, but in essence what you want to do is pass a reference to the selected Industry value to the 2nd Table View Controller.

Here's one way to do that. First, create a class-level variable for Industry in the 2nd table VC.

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var industry: Industry?
}
```

Second, make use of the prepareForSegue() method in your 1st Table VC to pass the instance of Industry to the new view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "IndustryPush" {
        let secondTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        secondTableViewController.industry = sender as! Industry            
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a reference to the selected industry in your first VC. (You set that in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.) And then you can pass THAT to the second VC in prepareForSegue().

From there, it's on you to figure out how to use the Industry instance to filter your JSON. It's a little hard to tell from what you've posted.

Hope that helps.